# On tangent space to the fundamental group scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves, fundamental-group

Let $X$ be a smooth, projective complex curve of genus at least $2$. If I understand correctly, after choosing a base point, one can associate to $X$, a fundamental group scheme $\pi$. I am trying to learn the properties of this scheme, in particular, what is the tangent space $T_e \pi$ at the identity element $e$? Any reference on this topic will be most welcome.